# Dynamic element locator on a web table

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

My first test case is to Add a record which I have successfully automated. My second test case is to delete the record which I added in test case one. I need your help to locate the Delete button from the web table.First, I want to locate the row(based on the values in column1 and column2, in this case ACTION20ALIANT and 2018-01-07), then go to the last column of that row and click on Delete button.The location of Delete button varies depending on the name of the record. Below is my method which is giving an error.

```
public static void Test(WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.name("frmSMain"));
    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for (WebElement row : rows) {
      if(row.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[text()='ACTION20Aliant']/following-sibling::td[text()='   2018-01-07   ']")).getText().equals("   2018-01-07   "))
      row.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:last-child input")).click();
    }
 }
```

Code is not identifying my xpath:

> Unable to find element with `xpath ==  //tr/td[text()='ACTION20Aliant']/following-sibling::td[text()='   2018-01-07']`

[image]

Extended first td and td of delete button are below:
[image][image]

Comment: Can you show the expanded of the link? first `td`

Comment: Also show expanded the `td` for `delete`.

Comment: @lauda- I have added the expanded first td and td for delete. Please check.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: There is an article which talks about the similar requirement - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-finding-webelements-using-map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for a `tr` that has both of these `td`'s and continue from there.

Start point example:

```
//tr[.//a[text()='ACTION20Aliant']][.//td[text()='2018-01-07']]
```

This will return the `tr` that has these values, now you can append the selector you need.

What you need to append can look like:

```
//input[@value='Delete']
```

resulting in:

`//tr[.//a[text()='ACTION20Aliant']][.//td[text()='2018-01-07']]//input[@value='Delete']`

Now you can search the element, if found then use click on the returned object, else do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I tried below cod, still it says unable to find xpath `public static WebElement Test(WebDriver driver) {
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[.//a[text()='ACTION20Aliant']][.//td[text()='   2018-01-07   ']]//input[@value='Delete']"));
  return element;
 }`

Comment: @lauda- Many thanks for your solution. I did exactly what you said and it is working now. Below is my final xpath( Had to tweak a little) `//tr[.//a[text()='ACTION20Aliant']][.//td[contains(text(),'2018-01-07')]]//input[@value='Delete']`